# Jersey Response.seeOther() not giving HTTP 303 status code

Tags: java, jersey

I have a social networking site in which we have a restricted community.

When a guest user applies requests for membership, a membership request is generated. I am performing this task through a REST API.

I am using **RESTClient plugin** in firefox to send requests.

When I send a POST resquest for adding self to the restricted community, the response is the memebership request generated for the same. Hence, the underlying HTTP status code is `303 See Other POST/GET`.

I get proper response for the same with the membership request in response but the status code is `200 OK`(which I think is the code for the GET on the membership request).

But, I need the same to be 303. I have *tried debugging also*. My finding is that the Jersey `Response.seeOther()` is not returning 303.

Please help.

The code snippets are as follows :

addUserToCommunity method :

```
MembershipRequestModel membershipRequest = null;
membershipRequest = communityService.addUserToCommunity(communityId, userId);
if(membershipRequest != null) {
  // Add code 303 if returning membershiprequest
  return seeOther( membershipRequest, 
                   String.valueOf(membershipRequest.getId()), 
                   MembershipRequestRestHandlerImpl.class);
} else {
  return ok(null);
}

seeOther method which in turn calls Response.seeOther() :

public Response seeOther(Object model, String id, Class<?> resource){

  URI location = buildLocation(resource, id);

  return Response.seeOther(location).entity(createResponseItems(model)).build();
}
```

Comment: could you attach at least signature of your POST method and how you forming a response.

Comment: Hey Alex, I have added the code snippets to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

303 - See Other is essentially a redirect - browser would automatically follow the URL provided in location header. Are you sure this is not what you see? I.e. maybe the firefox plugin you are using is simply following the redirect (behind the scenes) and returning the result of a GET method on that location URL. Try FireBug which shows you exact requests that went on the wire - you should be able to see the redirect there.

Comment: That's a correct behavior. All 20x responses mean OK, 204 is used specifically when the result is OK, but no entity is sent on the wire - which is exactly your case.  Why is that a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to geht the 303 instead of the 200 Response:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false);
```

The redirect URL ist in the Location: header

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem with RESTClient i.e; the browser as Martin says.

The browser actually performs the redirect and does not give 303.

Instead try hitting the URI using cURL in the shell or using puTTY. It works fine.

Thank you.