# clarification about use of response.seeother in jersey

Tags: java, jax-ws, jersey

Can anybody tell  exactly use of Response.seeOther(...) in jersey

i am trying to use this method but this will not affect in execution.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in Post-Redirect-Get pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: i know this is used for this purpose
but how to achieve this my problem is described in my question (i am trying to use this method but this will not affect in execution.)

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what problem you're having? It should essentially send you a 303 redirect with the URI you give to Response.seeOther(URI). Your client needs to read this though and follow the redirect.

Comment: See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905336/jersey-response-seeother-not-giving-http-303-status-code